# Cannot simulate form clicks in Redux-Form unit test

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to simulate a form submission in redux-form for a unit-test and I can't even get the onSubmit handler to be called.

## Test Snippet

```
import React from 'react';
import { AddBudgetForm } from '../../../src/Budget/components/AddBudgetForm';
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("AddBudgetForm Component", () => {
  let budgetForm = null;
  let submitting, touched, error, reset,addBudget, addBudgetResponse, handleSubmit
  beforeEach(() => {
    submitting = false
    touched = false
    error = null
    reset = sinon.spy()
    addBudgetResponse = Promise.resolve()
    handleSubmit = fn => fn
  })
  const buildForm = () => {
    addBudget = sinon.stub().returns(addBudgetResponse)
    const props = {
      addBudget,
      submitting: submitting,
      fields: {
        budgetName: {
          value: '',
          touched: touched,
          error: error
        }
      },
      handleSubmit,
      reset
    }
    return shallow(<AddBudgetForm {...props}/>)
  }

  it ('Calls reset after onSave', () => {
    budgetForm = buildForm();
    budgetForm.find('[type="submit"]').simulate('submit')
  })

})
```

Above, I'm mocking some of the actions and my test will inevitably just check the callCount from the `sinon spy`.

## Form

```
  submit(dataValues) {
    console.log("called")
    dataValues.preventDefault();
    this.props.addBudget({})

  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className='form-group has-danger'>
         <form onSubmit={(e) => this.submit(e)}>
          <Field name='budgetName' component={this.categoryInput} placeholder="Enter Category of Budget" label="Budget Category"/>
          <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I've shortened my code a bit, but the idea is that the onSubmit should call the function, but I can't even get the console log to print. Not really sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a submit event you should select a form tag. With the code above should be a click. So:

```
budgetForm.find('[type="submit"]').simulate('click')
```